# How to extract the table values and load into pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, pyquery

I have this code. I am trying to extract data from [this website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/passenger-volumes) into pandas.

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.tsa.gov/travel/passenger-volumes"
content = requests.get(url).content
doc = pq(content)
Passengers = doc(".views-align-center").text()
```

Method 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for x in Passengers.split(' ')]) 
print(df)
```

Method 2:

```
Passengers = Passengers.replace(' ',';')
Passengers
```

For Method 1, is it possible to do pandas data frame [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to get proper table structure?

Or is it better to do Method 2? How to split string periodically and load into pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
url = "https://www.tsa.gov/travel/passenger-volumes"
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)   # gives a list of the DFs extracted
print(df_list[0])
```

which gives the DataFrame:

```
          Date       2023     2022     2021    2020     2019
0     6/1/2023  2463873.0  2228271  1815931  391882  2623947
1    5/31/2023  2255052.0  2023231  1587910  304436  2370152
2    5/30/2023  2342489.0  2114935  1682752  267742  2247421
3    5/29/2023  2577437.0  2319237  1900170  353261  2499002
4    5/28/2023  2257766.0  2103022  1650454  352947  2555578
..         ...        ...      ...      ...     ...      ...
359   6/7/2022        NaN  2052377  1560561  338382  2433189
360   6/6/2022        NaN  2279743  1828396  430414  2644981
361   6/5/2022        NaN  2387196  1984658  441255  2669860
362   6/4/2022        NaN  1981408  1681192  353016  2225952
363   6/3/2022        NaN  2332592  1879885  419675  2649808

[364 rows x 6 columns]
```

The NaN values in 2023 force the float dtype but you can then clean the data as required. For example:

```
df = df_list[0]
df['2023']= df['2023'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```